# Printing Bitmap Using Bluetooth Thermal Printer With Firemonkey Android

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, firemonkey, thermal-printer

I have this code is success for printing text with bluetooth thermal printer using android using firemonkey delphi, 
my friend modified for printing bitmap, but any some error access violation with procedure bitmaptostr.

```
procedure TBluetoothPrinter.Send(Data: TArray<Byte>);
begin
  if Data = nil then
    Exit; // nothing to write

  Check(OutputStream <> nil, 'Cannot retrieve output stream');
  OutputStream.write(ToJavaByteArray(Data));
end;

procedure Printing(sText: string);
begin
  with TBluetoothPrinter.Create do
  begin
    Send(TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(sText + CRLF));
  end;
end;

function BitmapToStr(BMP: TBitmap; EscapeStr:String; SliceEscapeStr:String; BitsSlice: Byte = 8):String;
var
  BMPData: TBitmapData;
  AColor: TAlphaColor;

  nCol, nRow, nIndex: integer;
  nOffset, nBytePos, nBitPos: integer;
  nSliceIndex, nLum: integer;
  nSlice, nBit, nTmpBit, BytesSlice: byte;
  ADots: Array of boolean;
  sSlice: String;
begin
  try
    SetLength(ADots, (BMP.Height * BMP.Width));
    nIndex := 0;

    for nRow := 0 to BMP.Height-1 do
    begin
      for nCol := 0 to BMP.Width-1 do
      begin
        AColor := BMPData.GetPixel(nCol, nRow);
        nLum := Trunc((TAlphaColorRec(AColor).R * 0.3)  + (TAlphaColorRec(AColor).G * 0.59) + (TAlphaColorRec(AColor).B * 0.11));
        ADots[nIndex] := (nLum < 127);
        inc(nIndex);
      end;
    end;

   BytesSlice := (BitsSlice div 8);

    if BitsSlice mod 8 > 0 then
      inc(BytesSlice);

    Result := EscapeStr;
    nOffset := 0;
    while (nOffset < BMP.Height) do
    begin
      Result := Result + SliceEscapeStr;

      for nCol := 0 to BMP.Width-1 do
      begin
        for nSliceIndex := 0 to BytesSlice - 1 do
        begin
          nSlice := 0;
          for nBit := 0 to 7 do
          begin
            nBytePos := (((nOffset div 8) + nSliceIndex) * 8) + nBit;
            nBitPos := (nBytePos * BMP.Width) + nCol;

            nTmpBit := 0;
            if (nBitPos < Length(ADots)) then
            begin
              if ADots[nBitPos] then
                nTmpBit := 1
              else
                nTmpBit := 0;
            end;
            nSlice := nSlice or (nTmpBit shl (7 - nBit));
          end;

          Result := Result + Chr(nSlice);
        end;
      end;

      inc(nOffset, BitsSlice);
      Result := Result + CRLF;
    end;
  finally
     ADots := nil;
  end;
end;
```

anyone have some solution or sample reference?

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you even need function BitmapToStr for printing of Bitmap on your printer. I haven't seen any printer yet to be able to print a bitmap from a bunch of text. Usually they require bitmap data in binary formant and of course a specific command to tell the printer that next block of data represents image and not just text.

Comment: maybe do you have sugest code.

Comment: I'm afraid no as it might also depend from printer to printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have in `BitmapToStr()` is that you never `Map` the `BMPData` with the `BMP` bitmap.

Add this to the beginning of the function:

```
bmp.Map(TMapAccess.Read, BMPData);
try
  ...
```

and at the end:

```
finally
  bmp.Unmap(BMPData);
end;
```

On the other hand, you don't need the `try..finally..end` block to assure proper cleanup of the `ADots` array.

Comment: av error has disappeared, it turns out this idea can not be used for printing as said by @SilverWarrior

Comment: @mgk First you need to understand that the main principle on SO is "one question per post". Posts that are not focused on that principle are often closed as "too broad". Now, you described your problem as: *..some error access violation with procedure bitmaptostr.* and asked the question: *anyone have some solution..?* which I answered and which you now also confirmed to be correct answer: *av error has disappeared...*. That you also have other problems with your code, does not take anything away from the fact that I answered your question. Post a new question regarding your transfer algorithm